# Qt signal transition on parent state overriden by child state

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

In my `QStateMachine`, I have a `QState parent` that has several children states `child1`, `child2` and `child3`. I want all children to have a common response to the signal `MyStruct::mySignal()`. However, I also want `child1` to do something more on that signal. I thought of creating a `QSignalTransition` on the parent with the common response, and creating another one with the specific behavior for `child1` (see the code below).

```cpp
struct MyStruct {
  Q_OBJECT

  Q_SIGNAL void mySignal();

  void commonResponse() {
    std::cout << "Common" << std::endl;
  }

  void specificResponse() {
    std::cout << "Specific" << std::endl;
  }
};

QState* parent = new QState();
QState* child1 = new QState(parent);
QState* child2 = new QState(parent);
QState* child3 = new QState(parent);

MyStruct myStruct;

QSignalTransition* commonTransition = new QSignalTransition(&myStruct, &MyStruct::mySignal);
parent->addTransition(commonTransition);
connect(commonTransition , &QAbstractTransition::triggered, &myStruct, &MyStruct::commonResponse);

QSignalTransition* specificTransition = new QSignalTransition(&myStruct, &MyStruct::mySignal);
child1->addTransition(specificTransition);
connect(specificTransition, &QAbstractTransition::triggered, &myStruct, &MyStruct::specificResponse);
```

However with this code, if I am currently in state `child1` and a `MyStruct::mySignal` is emitted, then it will only output *Specific*. Is it possible to get the expected behavior of printing both *Common* and *Specific* while keeping the code clarity? (without adding a duplicate `MyStruct::mySignal` for the specific case, or having to "remember" to call `commonResponse` in `specificResponse`)

Answer (score 1):

Here with your code, Conceptually you are overriding the inherited transition from the base class. `child1->addTransition(specificTransition);` overrides the parents `addTransition`.

Look into below documentation link and search for

> A child state can override an inherited transition

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/statemachine-api.html

As the parent transition is overridden, the only way you can achieve the expected behavior is by calling `commonResponse` from `specificResponse`

Or

Add the `commonResponse` behavior also in `specificResponse`, which is **not** a good idea in terms of **maintenance**.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Indeed the `child1->addTransition()` overrides the parent but only because they are both `QSignalTransition` with the same sender and signal. It's too bad there is not some kind of parameter that would act like "do not override the transition and allow new similar ones to be executed along with this one". I guess I'll have to sacrifice a bit of readability in my code to do what I want :(

Comment: @co2fgtr Yes. They should have provided a flag, to execute both. Of course we don't know what design complications, the library developers had in their mind.